FutureBuilder making UI/ExpansionTile slow/laggy
I have used FutureBuilder in a ExpansionTile, and when I click the ExpansionTile, there is always a noticeable lag, which is caused by the FutureBuilder. Please see below.

The app is working as required, but I am concerned with the lag when expanding the ExpansionTile.
Below is the code, how do I fix this?
class CustomListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String titleName;
  final String fileName;
  final String linkToFile;

  const CustomListTile(
      {super.key,
      required this.titleName,
      required this.fileName,
      required this.linkToFile});

  @override
  State<CustomListTile> createState() => _CustomListTileState();
}

class _CustomListTileState extends State<CustomListTile> {
  // Initialise the DownloadFile class // - refactored for readability
  DownloadPaper downloadPaper = DownloadPaper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      tileColor: Colors.white,
      horizontalTitleGap: 2,
      title: Text(widget.titleName),
      trailing: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: checkFile(widget.fileName),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      
            // return const CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {


            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          }
          bool fileExists = snapshot.data ?? false;

          return Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (!fileExists) {
                    downloadPaper.downloadPaper(
                      context,
                      widget.linkToFile,
                      widget.fileName,
                    );
                    
                  } else {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      const SnackBar(content: Text('File already exists')),
                    );
                  }
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.download_sharp),
                color: fileExists
                    ? Colors.blue
                    : const Color.fromARGB(255, 241, 166, 161),
                tooltip: 'Offline Download',
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (ctx) => Center(
                      child: AlertDialog(
                        title: const Text('Delete'),
                        content: const Text('Delete from storage?'),
                        actions: [
                          Center(
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('No'),
                                ),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    downloadPaper.deleteFile(
                                      context,
                                      widget.fileName,
                                    );
                                    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('Yes'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever_outlined),
                tooltip: 'Delete',
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // bananaOpenTask(
                  //     '0def1cfb-e2b5-48ee-bc02-6ecc4ad59666');
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.share_outlined),
                tooltip: file_name.shareTooltip,
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PdfViewer(
              subjectLink: widget.linkToFile,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<bool> checkFile(String fileName) async {
    bool checkFile = await downloadPaper.checkFile(fileName);

    return checkFile;
  } // close checkFile()
} // close class


Could you try making the widget Stateless seeing as its less expensive than a Stateful widget
